# AppMessages Sporadically Don't Get Delivered

Tags: android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-appmessage

I have an issue where I when I send a message from the Android side (within a broadcast receiver) the messages don't always make it to the Pebble watch.  It's inconsistent, sometimes it works.

I'm not getting an APP_MSG_BUSY result any longer (I am only trying to send exactly one message Android->Pebble).

This is quite simply how I'm sending the small amount of data (<64 bytes):

```
PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble(context, appUuid, dict)
```

I have the inbox and outbox size configured for their maximum.

And on the pebble side I've registered my callback and I deal with the message as so:

```
static void inbox_received_callback(DictionaryIterator *iter, void *context) {
   // A new message has been successfully received
   APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "Message received");
}
```

*Note: There is also an `inbox_dropped_callback` registered but I've not included that for brevity.*

I've properly N/ACK'd the message on the Android side (learned that the hard way), but I don't see a way to N/ACK the message on the Pebble side.  I'm assuming that providing a callback is enough?

The good news is that it sometimes works, so I know I have everything configured properly.  The bad news is that when it stops working it stops working almost entirely and for quite some time (15 minutes or longer).  I suspect the inbox is filling, but I don't know how to check.

EDIT: I added both an Ack and a Nack handler on the Android side and I'm getting a Nack when I send a message.  I need to figure out why my Pebble watch is not allowing things.  Any guesses?

I also find this in logcat from Android:

```
10-05 13:16:37.206 8361-2610/? W/Pbl: [AppMessage]  there is not UUID for transactionId : -1
```

I have confirmed that my UUID is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [timing](https://forums.pebble.com/t/send-timeout-when-sending-app-msg-to-pebblekit-js/12240) issue.  After researching online and finding the referenced post I added a psleep(1000) to my code and it works fine.  I was sending the message while the app was still starting up.

I did find the [event listener](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/pebblekit-js/Pebble/#addEventListener), but this is JS based and my app is written in C.

Hope this helps someone!